# How do I test an AWS Lambda Function that is triggered by EventBridge but needs to be aware of daylight savings?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, testing

I have a lambda function that needs to run at a user defined frequency, defined via cron, at 9 AM Eastern time. For example, "weekdays at 9 AM" or "every alternate day at 9 AM".

EventBridge (via CDK) only allows me to define the cron trigger based on UTC. I'm triggering the function at 1 PM as well as 2 PM UTC, to account for daylight savings, and detecting whether daylight savings is in effect in the lambda code. That way, I can skip if it isn't 9 AM Eastern time and run the actual code when it really is 9 AM.

Here's how the code looks like:

```
def aws_lambda(event, context):
  cron_expression = os.getenv('cron_expression')  # The cron in CDK also passed as env var
  local_time = localized_time_now()
  
  if local_time.hour != 9:
    return
  
  window_start = local_time - timedelta(days=1)
  window_stop = local_time

  iter = croniter(cron_expression, window_start, ret_val=datetime)
  prev_invocation = iter.get_prev()
  if prev_invocation > window_start:
    raise RuntimeError("Cron expression needs to allow for 24 hours to pass between events")

  # Business logic here, using window_start and window_stop to query the DB
  ...
```

How do I test this function? I can't control the server time in EventBridge or Lambda, so it seems inherently untestable. It seems like the `localized_time_now()` function is key, but I'll just have to trust that it will always work properly in the context of AWS?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion `localized_time_now()` works with the `TZ` [environment variable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html) (look for TZ). So You have to set this varialble to Your timezone first. This is of course possible with CDK.

```js
environment: {
        TZ: 'Europe/Berlin',
      }
```

After that `datetime.datetime.now()` should return the local time.
This is kind of awful that we can only set the event schedule in UTC, but it is how it is and running the lambda every hour and checking if it is the correct one is a valid solution for me here.

The second thing is how to test this. You can of course run this lambda locally with diffrent event timestamps. You can do unit tests or probably better at this point would be to use the [lambda-local package](https://pypi.org/project/python-lambda-local/). Consider also playng around with test events in the lambda console. There You can play around with the actual runtime.